# MockedStatic with arguments says "Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, mockstatic

I have one class where one public non-static method executes a static method call inside requires to mock static when I tried to test in junit with mockito.

**What did i do wrong?**

```
class DummyClass {

    public boolean filter(CharSequence source) {
        return Character.isHighSurrogate(source.charAt(7));
    }
}

@Test
public void testDummyCharacterMockedStatic() {
   try (MockedStatic<Character> mocked = Mockito.mockedStatic(Character.class)) {
       CharSequence source = "안녕하세요 세계";
       mocked.when(() -> Character.isHighSurrogate(anyChar())).thenReturn(true);
       DummyClass d = new DummyClass();
       assertTrue(d.filter(source));
   }
}
```

Error shows the following >>>>

> Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at DummyTest.lambda$testDummyCharacterMockedStatic$0(DummyTest.java:37)
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
> Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
> when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
> doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
> verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last
> matcher is returning an object  like any() but the stubbed method
> signature expect a primitive argument, in this case, use primitive
> alternatives.
> when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
> when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
> methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
> stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods
> declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

***No possible for the types we don't own***

"Character" is a type from "java.lang.*" package

*Caveat*

The inline mock maker is an optional feature of Mockito.

Mockito includes this note in the JavaDoc for Mockito.mockStatic.

> Note: We recommend against mocking static methods of classes in the standard library or classes used by custom class loaders used to
> executed the block with the mocked class. A mock maker might forbid
> mocking static methods of know [sic] classes that are known to cause
> problems. Also, if a static method is a JVM-intrinsic, it cannot
> typically be mocked even if not explicitly forbidden.

The error messages issued by Mockito.mockStatic can be broad and confusing. The static mocking of low-level standard library classes can be unreliable and have unpredictable effects. It may take some experimentation to fine-tune use of this powerful feature.

Ref: https://site.mockito.org/ > "More"

> Remember
>
> - Do not mock types you don’t own
> - Don’t mock value objects
> - Don’t mock everything
> - Show love with your tests!